# I cannot install the Tiled Map Editor on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: mac, macbook-pro, install

I am attempting to install [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/), a cross-platform open-source application that uses the QT application framework. It is used in game design.

When I attempt to install it, I get this error message:

> You can't open the application Qt SDK Installer because it is not
>   supported on this type of Mac

How can I resolve this problem? I am using Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the application you are using is Intel supported. I don't know why a PPC application **wouldn't** run on an Intel, but try clicking on the application, go to File>Get Info, and under General>Kind, check to see what the application kind is.[image]

Comment: In my file->get info, "Kind = Disk Image", Is it correct and thanks for your feedback guys:)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize that you were installing it from a dmg. Hmm...that is really puzzling.

Comment: Yes. I was installing dmg format file because it is run with mac OS. Any problem with dmg file?

Comment: I have never had a problem with a dmg file until this morning and it's not related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know which version of OS X you're running.

- You must have Xcode installed on your machine.
- It's possible you have downloaded the 64bit version.
- Verify you have the correct version.

Comment: I have updated the OS version in my question

Comment: You should be fine with your OS version, so the next question is do you have Xcode installed?

Comment: Yas i have installed xcode

Comment: Which installer are you using — the offline version or the online?

Comment: Yeah, check to make sure you downloaded the correct version. Where did you download/get it from?

Comment: Try using the online installer: http://qt.nokia.com/downloads

Comment: I have installed Qt from the same link :( but why this error occur still, I don't know